# Related model of a selected element when multiple models are loaded

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am wondering if there is any way to figure out to what model a selected element belongs when multiple models are loaded in Forge Viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscribe to the you'd be provided with the target model object as well:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,event=>{
//event {type: "aggregateSelection", selections: Array(1), target: T}
//selections: Array(1)
//0: {fragIdsArray: Array(2), dbIdArray: Array(1), nodeArray: Array(1), model: u}
}
```